# Controlling VESC with Esp32

Tags: arduino

I am working on a DIY Project where i have to control some brushless motors so i went for the vesc and i am using vesc 6. I have already done the configuration on the vesc tool.
I am trying to use the internal IMU and other functionalities of the vesc so i thought about connecting it to a microcontroler and i am using a heltek lora32. i used many libraries but none of them worked with my board then i found this project : https://hadi.timachi.com/project/7/DIY_mountain_e_bike_version_2
i started digging a little on the library used but same i ge nothing from my vesc.

I am willing to know if there is a way to connect my vesc to the microcontroler via UART.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: based on the little information you've given, it could be at least a million possibilities. Try to narrow it down for us. What works and what doesn't work? How is it wired? How have you checked the wiring?

Comment: You're asking for the answer "yes there is" which is almost certainly correct but probably doesn't help you very much. You may need to ask a better question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. @Kartman and user_1818839. I got it to work and it was a problem on the code used, now i can recover some infos but still not the imu data. I sent the command : COMM_GET_IMU_DATA or 2 1 65 88 229 3 0 but i can not figure out how it is parsed. This is the response i m getting e.g : https://pastebin.com/nJC3ZpX5.